# Magento dont send transactional mails

Tags: email, transactional, ce-1.9.1.0

My Magento only send mails from `app\locale\en_US\template\email` (confirmation mail, new account, ...)

dont send from `app\locale\en_US\template\email\sales` or the transactional mails.

I create new templates and applied in system > configuration > sales > sales e-mails
but dont work, nothing in magento or server log.

In configuration > system, disable email communications is NO

My host is running Linux with nginx/postfix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Magento 1.9.1.0 all Magento e-mails (including order confirmation and transactional) are now queued and sent according to your configured cron schedule.

From the [release notes](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ce19-later-release-notes):

> It's more important than ever for you to configure a Magento cron job.
>   In addition to indexing and other core functions, all Magento e-mails
>   (including order confirmation and transactional) are now queued and
>   sent according to your configured cron schedule.

So I think you have to check configuration of Magento Cron Job. [Here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ce18-and-ee113-installing#install-cron) you can learn more about how to set them up.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted!