# Does Magento 1 log transactional mails that were sent?

Tags: admin, magento-1, order-email, transactional-mail, order-confirmation

Can you view the automated transactional emails that have been sent by the system like order confirmations, password forgotten-mails and more? Is there some kind of a mail log which you can view afterwards?

Comment: Shameless plug... The extension [Modulwerft E-Mail-Manager](https://en.modulwerft.com/magento-e-mail-manager.html) might help with that.

Answer (score 8):

The new 1.9.1 Email System leverages [two database tables to queue, process, and log transactional order confirmation emails](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/46063/magento-1-9-1-email-queue-not-working-buggy-how-to-troubleshoot-and-what-is-co) sent after customers checkout:

1. `core_email_queue` This stores data relating the emails that are sent for order confirmations
2. `core_email_queue_recipients` - This stores the email addresses of the recipients of the emails stored in `core_email_queue`

Troubleshooting issues with this new functionality can be difficult.  The link above is fairly technical but covers the key areas.  I also have had success with following [this process in my own troubleshooting](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/62264/some-transactional-emails-are-not-being-sent), though the issues I ran into were specific to my environments so your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 1):

In magento 1.9.1.0 there is email queue table. In previous magento versions most probably you can find only was email sent or not. In tables sales_flat_* (order/invoice/shipment) there is such field as 'email_sent'. Which has only true/false value. The email address you can also find in same table.